# Order of growth of the error term of the log-exponent of the average prime gap

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, goldbach-type-problems

Disclaimer: I might have already asked this question or a very similar one but couldn't find it if it is so. Hope it will be judged somehow interesting anyway.

Assuming Goldbach's conjecture, let's write once again $r_{0}(n):=\inf\{r>0,(n-r,n+r)\in\mathbb{P}^{2}\}$ for every large enough composite natural number $n$ and $k_{0}(n):=\pi(n+r_{0}(n))-\pi(n-r_{0}(n))$.

The prime number theorem implies that the limit as $k_{0}(n)$ tends to $\infty$ of $a(n):=\frac{\log \frac{2r_{0}(n)}{k_{0}(n)}}{\log\log n}$ exists and equals $1$. Of course, letting $k_{0}(n)$ tend to $\infty$ implies that $n$ also tends to $\infty$. Under Cramer's conjecture, $\displaystyle{\limsup_{\substack{k_{0}(n)=1\\n\to\infty}}a(n)=2}$, so writing $a(n)=1+f(k_{0}(n))$ entails, under those two conjectures, that $f(1)\lesssim 1$ while $\displaystyle {\lim_{k_{0}(n)\to\infty}f(k_{0}(n))=0}$.

So my question is: which order of growth of $f(k_{0}(n))$ in terms of $k_{0}(n)$ can be obtained "as unconditionnally as possible"? A discussion of the consequences of, say, the Hardy-Littlewood $k$-tuple conjecture alone provided $r_{0}(n)$ exists would be also interesting.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "the limit as $k_0(n)$ tends to $\infty$ of $a(n)$ exists and equals $1$". The notion of "limit of $f(n)$ as $g(n)\to\infty$" in general is not well-defined, and a naive interpretation I came up with failed, since there exists a sequence $n_m$ such that $k_0(n_m)\to\infty$ but with $a(n_m)\to 0$. Could you clarify what exactly is the statement you are asserting?

Comment: Hm, that's interesting. I wanted to formalize that on average the gap between two consecutive primes in the interval $[n-r_{0}(n),n+r_{0}(n)]$ is around $\log n$, so I may have to consider the average order of $a(n)$ rather than the limit.

Comment: Wojowu: the upper bound I conjecture in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376876/does-one-have-2r-0n-lesssim-k-0n-log-n11-k-0n may help clarify what I mean, namely that the larger $k_{0}(n)$ the closer $2r_{0}(n)/k_{0}(n)$ gets to $\log n$.